# Android AccessibilityService prevents keyboard from appearing

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, accessibilityservice

I am creating an AccessibilityService which sometimes displays screen overlays. When the service is active the keyboard does no longer appear when clicking text fields.

What can cause this?

I'm using the following accessibility properties:

```xml
<accessibility-service android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeWindowContentChanged"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.assistant.SettingsActivity"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Accessibility Service properties are fine, there is something else going on. Does none of the apps on your phone having edit Text/input text show soft keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, none. It's as if it thinks the AccessibilityService is supposed to replace the keyboard.

Comment: What are you doing in your logic when the service starts?